# LINQPAD - TypeLoadException

Tags: linq, linqpad

I am seeing the following error in LINQPad (typeloadexception in first screenshot):

[image]

Here are the connection properties:

[image]

The 'Test' button works as expected i.e. it prompts: "Successful".  What is the problem? Here is the web.config in the app:

```
<add name="AdventureWorks2012Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=mypc;initial catalog=AdventureWorks2012;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I have read a few answers on here, which suggest setting the assembly to 32 bit etc.

Comment: Expand the error in the results box. What does it say under 'Inner Exception'?

Comment: @Joe Albahari, the inner exception is: "The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your custom assembly is named `LINQPad.dll`, which is likely to get confused with `LINQPad.exe`. You will need to change the assembly name in Visual Studio's project properties dialog.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I have spent two evenings trying to figure out what is wrong with this.  I have used Process Explorer; reinstalled Linqpad; changed app to 32 Bit and lots more.  This worked.